# C# Reflection Getting static property of concrete class from Interface

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an interface:

```
interface IInterface 
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

that is implemented by an generic abstract class:

```
public class BInterface<T> : IInterface
{
    static BInterface() 
    { 
        // Or anything that would be implementation class specific
        Name = typeof(BInterface<>).GetType().Name;  
    }
    public static string Name { get; private set; }
    string IInterface.Name { get { return Name; } }
}
```

Which is in turn implemented in a concrete class:

```
public class CInterface : BInterface<int> 
{
}
```

I know how to get the references to the concrete classes via 'type.IsAssignableFrom', '!type.IsInterface' and '!type.IsAbstract', but that is as far as I have managed.

I need to get, via Reflection, the VALUE of the static Name property for any of the concrete classes.  However, for the life of my poor brain, I cannot figure the code to accomplish this.  Any hints would be great.

**EDIT (In clarification):**

I am aware that the static property needs to read from the base class. However....

The static field will contain the base name of the concrete class --> derived via reflection in the static constructor of the base class.  This works (and I know how to accomplish it) as we do it all over the place.

I this case, I am attempting to build a factory class that needs to know this static field, and needs to get to it via Reflection due to the some (other) requirements of the factory implementation.

**EDIT (again) Expanded code:**

Here is a nearly complete, if useless, example of what I am attempting to accomplish.

```
    public interface IInterface
    {
        string Name { get; }
        object Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class BInterface<T> : IInterface
    {
        static BInterface()
        {
            // Or anything that would be implementation class specific
            Name = typeof(BInterface<>).GetType().Name; // Should be CInterface, DInterface depending on which class it is called from.
        }

    string IInterface.Name { get { return Name; } }
    object IInterface.Value { get { return Value; } set { Value = (T)value; } }

    public static string Name { get; private set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class CInterface : BInterface<int>
{
}

public class DInterface : BInterface<double>
{
}

public static class InterfaceFactory
{
    private readonly static IDictionary<string, Type> InterfaceClasses;

    static InterfaceFactory()
    {
        InterfaceClasses = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var interfaceTypes = assembly.GetTypes()
                                     .Where( type => type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (IInterface)) 
                                         && !type.IsInterface 
                                         && !type.IsAbstract);
        foreach (var type in interfaceTypes)
        {
            // Get name somehow
            var name = "...";
            InterfaceClasses.Add(name, type);
        }
    }

    public static IInterface Create(string key, object value, params object[] parameters)
    {
        if (InterfaceClasses.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            var instance = (IInterface) Activator.CreateInstance(InterfaceClasses[key], parameters);
            instance.Value = value;

            return instance;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The part in the static constructor of the IntefaceFactory inside the foreach loop is what I am attempting to solve.  Hopefully, this is clearer.

Comment: Why does it have to be through Reflection? Your implementation class clearly returns the `static` property as its implementation. Any concrete instance of the class will thus return that `static` property by just using the interface.

Comment: @pickypg: That's kind of missing the point of the question. The OP clearly thinks each inherited member gets its own "class instance" of the `static` member `Name` that will differ for each class. This is, of course, not the case.

Comment: @Jason I kind of agree, but I think the entire desire is either misguided or homework.

Comment: @pickypg: We are in agreement.

Comment: I don't think your code compiles. You are accessing a static property `Name` from an instance method `IInterface.Name` directly in the class `BInterface<T>`.

Comment: @David Williams: Your clarification didn't clarify. It just muddled the question further. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your example is too convoluted and definitely won't work as I can see several errors. It would be better if you could just state clearly what you want to accomplish (without context). For example: are you saying that you need to get the value of a static property from an abstract class using reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to get static property of concrete class from the instance:

```
var staticProperty = instance.GetType()
    .GetProperty("<PropertyName>", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var value = staticProperty.GetValue(instance, null);
```

Comment: @Ed S - I tried to find some. At least I found sense in the question title and did exactly what question title asks.

Answer (score 1):

`static` members don't work the way you are thinking. They belong to the base class and thus what you are attempting is not possible with a `static` inherited member.